# Why are node modules so large?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemon

I am new to Node. I just tried installing `nodemon` and that resulted in a huge `node modules` folder with more than 100 folders. Is `nodemon` actually that big or am I doing something wrong. I used the following commmand:

```
npm i nodemon -D
```

Comment: Nodemon has dependencies and these dependencies will have dependencies, it's normal https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/main/package.json#L59

Comment: I was following a tutorial and there it seems only a couple of folders were created. Was this added in a later version of Node?

Comment: (much) older versions of NPM handled the folder structure differently, but the same number of folders were created... just in a different way. More recent versions of NPM use far less folder nesting, so you end up with far more folders at the top.

Comment: Welcome to the world of Node.js. It is considered both an advantage and a drawback. The ecosystem is absolutely huge, there is a total lack of any standards or standard libraries and every package brings gazillions of other packages. It was one of the reason behind its original author created Deno.
https://twitter.com/garrows/status/1065217184643768320

Answer (score 0):

Because nodemon is built with other npm packages. You can see the dependencies in its official page:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

And in turn the dependencies may depend on other modules. That's why node_modules can have many files. But don't worry, this is normal.